# How to choose which Excel version is used for debugging a VSTO project with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, vsto, excel-addins, office-addins

I have developed an Excel add-in with Visual Studio 2010. When I debug my project, the add-in is loaded in Microsoft Excel 2010.
Now I have also installed Office 2013 on my computer, and I'd like to use it for debugging my project, but Excel 2010 is still executed by default.

Is there a way to choose which version of Excel is used for debugging a VSTO project in Visual Studio 2010? Or can I at least set Excel 2013 as the default program?

Answer (score 3):

I managed to choose the version of Excel by editing the project properties in the .csproj project file.

I changed:

`<ProjectProperties HostName="Excel" HostPackage="..." OfficeVersion="14.0" VstxVersion="4.0" ApplicationType="Excel" Language="cs" TemplatesPath="" DebugInfoExeName="#Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Excel\InstallRoot\Path#excel.exe" AddItemTemplatesGuid="..." />`

to:

`<ProjectProperties HostName="Excel" HostPackage="..." OfficeVersion="15.0" VstxVersion="4.0" ApplicationType="Excel" Language="cs" TemplatesPath="" DebugInfoExeName="#Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Excel\InstallRoot\Path#excel.exe" AddItemTemplatesGuid="..." />`.

Answer (score 2):

have you tried to set the debug executable?

Project->Properties->Debug->Start Action->Start external program

Comment: Thank you for your help Alex, I finally managed to find a solution by editing the project properties in the .csproj project file. It seems that your suggestion would work for executing the correct version of the program, but it would not support breaking points etc.

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

1. Select executable project rebuild it in debug mode.
2. Go to bin folder and open the excel application there, by default it opens in latest version.
3. Go to Visual Studio Debug: click on "Attach to Process" search to select Excel.exe process.
4. After selecting click on Attach.
5. Now you can debug with latest excel version.